# Getting Dojo widgets like dojox.layout.ContentPane working for Android apps developed using Cordova with NetBeans

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, netbeans, dojo

I'm trying to get widgets like dojox.layout.ContentPane working properly in a Netbeans Cordova environment for Android and iOS. I'm using as the main contentPane that will render the pages based on what the user press. Is it possible to get it working or are there better alternatives in Dojo for this purpose?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
       require([
            "dojox/layout/ContentPane",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(
            ContentPane,
            registry
        ) {
            var contentPanel = new ContentPane({
                ioMethod: dojo.xhrPost,
                executeScripts:"true",
                style: "height: 100%",
                region:"center"
            },"contentPanel");   

            contentPanel.setHref("home.html");
```

});

```
<div id="contentPanel" padding-bottom:10px">
</div>
```

This is the error line that appears in firebug console

```
var error = new RequestError('Unable to load ' + response.url + ' status: ' + _xhr.status, response);
```

Update1: Am suspecting that this is related to Android SDK issue that many others are facing which is caused by _ characters in many of the Dojo files ([Google Issue link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343)). Dojo Build was suggested. But I have not manage to "build everything into 1 file" that has been suggested to work

The Dojo Build profile I tried:

```
var profile = (function(){
return {
    basePath: "./../../../../../web/html/js/",//file path start from Util\dojoSDK\util\buildscripts\profiles
    releaseDir: "./../../../Util/release",
    action: "release",
    layerOptimize: "closure",
    optimize: "shrinksafe",
    cssOptimize: "false",
    mini: false,
    stripConsole: "normal",
    selectorEngine: "acme",

    packages:[/**/{
        name: "dojo",
        location: "../../../Util/dojoSDK/dojo"
    },{
        name: "dojox",
        location: "../../../Util/dojoSDK/dojox"
    },{
        name: "dijit",
        location: "../../../Util/dojoSDK/dijit"
    }],

    layers: {
        "dojo/dojo": {
            include: [
                "dojo/dojo",
                "dojo/i18n",
                "dojo/domReady",
                "dojo/parser"

 *all .js files in Dojo with _*
            ],
            customBase: true,
            boot: true
        }
    }
};
})();
```

**FINAL UPDATE**: Apparently this is NOT caused by the underscore issue highlighted in Update1 above. I have reused the complete example code from [Dojo Flickr demo FINAL](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/mobile/flickrview/part5/index.html) and integrated dojox.layout.ContentPane to it and EVERYTHING works fine. Unable to say what exactly helped but I suspect it to be the way the dojo loader is written with things like dojox/mobile/parser and dojox/mobile/compat.

I have since looked into dojo.mobile modules as suggested by frank

Comment: I think you should be using [dojox/mobile/view](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile#views), which is specially designed for mobiles.

Comment: You should have a look here : http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html , Accordion may be what you want

Comment: @frank Exactly what I needed. Please post as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile layout you can use [dojox/mobile/view](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile#views).

Here is a good tutorial (sample mobile app) on dojo mobile to get you started.
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/mobile/flickrview/part2/